# problem running liquibase with maven and postgres-db

Tags: database, postgresql, maven, liquibase

I have a problem running maven's liquibase-plugin on a postgresql-db. 
When trying to run liquibase:update from the command-line, I get the error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-plugin:1.9.5.0:update (de
fault-cli) on project backend-persistence: Error setting up or running Liquibase
: liquibase.exception.JDBCException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE databasech
angeloglock (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WIT
H TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY
KEY (ID)): FEHLER: Relation ╗databasechangeloglock½ existiert bereits -> [Help 1
]
```

simply dropping the db-table does not help, it looks like liquibase is creating it twice, as the logfile suggests:

```
...
CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
COMMIT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO databasechangeloglock (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, false)
COMMIT
BEGIN
LECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM, c.relname AS TABLE_NAME,  CASE n.nspname 

....
CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
FEHLER:  Relation »databasechangeloglock« existiert bereits (already exists)
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Matthias

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the relevant pom snippet

Answer (score 2):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>${liquibase.propertyFile}</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably have multiple schema in your postgres database. To solve your problem, move all your data in the public schema.