# Liquibase ERROR: relation "databasechangeloglock" already exists

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, liquibase

While running Liquibase migration, the docker container is returning the following error:

> ```
> Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: relation 
> "databasechangeloglock" already exists [Failed SQL: 
> (0) CREATE TABLE public.databasechangeloglock (ID 
> INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
> LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY 
> VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT databasechangeloglock_pkey 
> PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
> ```

The IAM account which the liquibase is using has the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role.
Also, I queried for this table and it doesn't exist in the database.

Any thoughts on what this user could be missing? When I see the logs in gcp, I do see a permission error:

> `ERROR: permission denied for table databasechangeloglock`

However, this user seems to have permissions on all tables & sequences.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673003/how-to-setup-vault-and-postgres-in-google-cloud-to-have-the-correct-permissions)? This might help.

Comment: Yes, I found another post with the same error that had basically the same answer as @CatherineO gave above: [Liquibase: relation "databasechangeloglock" already exists, using grails plugin and non-default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683626/liquibase-relation-databasechangeloglock-already-exists-using-grails-plugin)

Comment: thank you! yes, it turned out to be a scenario where migration was initially run with a different user & when we added a new migration-specific user in Postgres, the new user wouldn't have permission on the databsechangeloglock table. I ended up creating a new database but the answer tagged by @CatherineO would have solved also solved it.

Comment: Thank you contributors to this post. I was able to solve my problem the same way. In my case we had switched to using Workload Identity in CloudSQL and doing this fixed it for us:

GRANT postgres TO "our-cloudsql-svcacct-user@gcp-project-name.iam";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Copied comment with the answer)

"It turned out to be a scenario where migration was initially run with a different user & when we added a new migration-specific user in Postgres, the new user wouldn't have permission on the databsechangeloglock table. I ended up creating a new database but the answer tagged by @CatherineO would have solved also solved it."

REFERENCES:

- [How to setup vault and Postgres in Google cloud to have the correct permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673003/how-to-setup-vault-and-postgres-in-google-cloud-to-have-the-correct-permissions)
- [Liquibase: relation "databasechangeloglock" already exists, using grails plugin and non-default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683626/liquibase-relation-databasechangeloglock-already-exists-using-grails-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

The mysql  may have disabled case sensicty where new one is case sencitivty enabled causing this issues, disabled case sencity, `lower_case_table_names=1` in `mysqld.conf` this error is solved